# Terminal window

Tags: command-line, sudo

New to Ubuntu 14.04.  How do I get to a terminal window?  Reason for question: I am wanting to do installs and workarounds with issues to do with DVDs and turning the music off when I close the music file.  Those routine-looking instructions come to a screeching halt for me when I am told to "open a terminal window" (to enter a sudo instruction).

Answer (score 0):

To open a terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> is going to be pressed at once.
You could also go into the Unity search function by pressing the <kbd>Super key</kbd> and entering "Terminal".  You will see Terminal show up under application.